# Como criar árvore binária com algoritmo iterativo?

Tags: c, struct, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Estou fazendo um programa que aloca um dicionário na memória para verificar palavras com erros ortográficos em arquivos de texto. A função abaixo converte as palavras do dicionário em inteiros e os armazena em estruturas árvore.

- Minha dúvida é como escrever **corretamente** e **iterativamente** a parte do
  código que vai armazenando os números na árvore(*a partir da linha 24*).

Vi muitos exemplos, mas todos recursivos e não entendi muito bem, fique à vontade em dar qualquer tipo de exemplo para outros usuários que possam ter a mesma dúvida.

```
typedef struct arvore
{
    unsigned int n;
    struct arvore *esq, *dir;
}arvore;

arvore *raiz;

unsigned int
BPHash(const char* str, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int hash;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; str++, i++)
        hash = hash << 7 ^ (*str);
    return hash;
}

bool
load(const char *dict)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(dict, "r"); // dict = arquivo que serve como dicionário
    if (fp == NULL)
        return false;

    char str[LENGTH+1]; // LENGTH = tamanho máximo da string (45)
    unsigned int strtam, hash; // Tamanho da string e string convertida em inteiro com função hash
    struct arvore dicio = {0, NULL, NULL};
    raiz = &dicio; // Ponteiro global

    while (fgets(str, LENGTH, fp) != NULL)
    {
        strtam = strlen(str);
        hash = BPHash(str, strtam); // BPHash = função hash

        if (raiz->n == 0) // Minha dúvida se refere as linhas abaixo
            raiz->n = hash;

        else if (raiz->n < hash)
        {
            raiz->esq = (arvore*)malloc(sizeof(arvore));
            raiz->dir = NULL;
            raiz->n = hash;
        }

        else
        {
            raiz->dir = (arvore*)malloc(sizeof(arvore));
            raiz->esq = NULL;
            raiz->n = hash;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar a sua função `BPHash` também?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu primeiro problema é que a raiz da árvore (`dicio`) está declarada dentro da própria função `load`, alocada estaticamente na pilha de execução (variáveis locais são alocadas na pilha de execução). Isso significa, que quando a função terminar, a parte correspondente da pilha de execução vai ser limpa e com ela a raiz da árvore. A raiz ainda poderia ser recuperada pela variável global `raiz`, mas isso vai ser um ponteiro que vai apontar para uma parte da pilha que não existe mais e que em breve será sobreescrita, tornando-se então em lixo.

A melhor solução para isso seria retornar a raiz da árvore ou `NULL` se ela não puder ser criada. Evite usar variáveis globais, pois fazer isso é uma péssima prática de programação. Mas, como você está sendo obrigado a trabalhar dessa forma, então infelizmente não há outra saída.

Outro problema é que a sua árvore tem no máximo três nós: `raiz`, `raiz->dir` e `raiz->esq`. Aliás, só terá dois, pois quando você cria o nó esquerdo, você apaga o direito e vice-versa. Além disso, você apaga esses nós sem desalocá-los, ocasionando vazamento de memória. Você nunca está criando ou acessando nós em níveis mais profundos.

Seu código revisado é esse:

```
// LENGTH = tamanho máximo da string
#define LENGTH 45

// função hash
unsigned int BPHash(const char *str, int len) {
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; str++, i++) {
        hash = hash << 7 ^ (*str);
    }
    return hash;
}

typedef struct arvore {
    unsigned int n;
    struct arvore *esq, *dir;
} arvore;

arvore *raiz = NULL;

bool load(const char *dict) {

    // Primeiro, destroi qualquer árvore que já houvesse antes, para evitar vazamento de memória.
    destruir_arvore(raiz);
    raiz = NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen(dict, "r"); // dict = arquivo que serve como dicionário
    if (fp == NULL) return false;

    char str[LENGTH + 1];

    while (fgets(str, LENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
        arvore *novo = (arvore *) malloc(sizeof(arvore));
        novo->n = BPHash(str, strlen(str));
        novo->esq = NULL;
        novo->dir = NULL;

        arvore *no = raiz;

        while (1) {
            if (no == NULL) {
               raiz = novo;
               break;
            } else if (no->n < hash) {
                if (no->esq == NULL) {
                    no->esq = novo;
                    break;
                }
                no = no->esq;
            } else {
                if (no->dir == NULL) {
                    no->dir = novo;
                    break;
                }
                no = no->dir;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Observe que temos dois `while`s aqui. O `while` externo percorre o arquivo lendo as strings dele, e a cada iteração, um nó `novo` é criado. O `while` interno usa um ponteiro `no`, que começa na `raiz` e vai descendo na árvore (`no = no->esq;` e `no = no->dir;`) até encontrar um lugar vazio onde o nó `novo` possa ser inserido. Quando o nó `novo` é inserido na árvore, dá-se um `break;` no `while` interno. O `if (no == NULL)` é para criar a raiz da árvore. Essa abordagem ainda tem a vantagem de que o zero não é especial e a função funciona mesmo se `BPHash` retornar zero. Não é utilizada recursão aqui.

Uma função para destruir a(s) árvore(s) criada(s) também é necessária a fim de evitar-se vazamentos de memória (dessa vez com recursão, já que a versão sem recursão é bem mais complicada):

```
void destruir_arvore(arvore *no) {
    if (no == NULL) return;
    destruir_arvore(no->esq);
    destruir_arvore(no->dir);
    free(no);
}
```

É claro que isso tudo depende de a função `BPHash` ter sido implementada adequadamente (faltou inicializar o `hash` com zero nela). Não sei se a implementação é ou não adequada. Também não sei se essa árvore será de fato útil ao que você quer, mas se for, é do jeito que coloquei acima que você irá construí-la.

Comment: Adicionei a função `BPHash` e mais alguns comentários.
_"Seu primeiro problema é que a `raiz` da árvore está declarada dentro da própria função `load`"_
O ponteiro `raiz` é uma variável global, está declarado fora de qualquer função.
_"A melhor solução para isso é retornar a raiz da árvore ou NULL se ela não puder ser criada"_
Neste exercício não posso mudar a declaração de `load`, tem que retornar um `bool`, por isso criei o ponteiro global raiz, para acessar a `arvore dicio` de qualquer função.

Comment: _"Aliás, só terá dois, pois quando você cria o nó esquerdo, você apaga o direito e vice-versa"_
Essa é minha maior dificuldade, criar novos nós iterativamente, e não sobrescrevê-los.
_"Além disso, você apaga esses nós sem desalocá-los, ocasionando vazamento de memória. Você nunca está criando ou acessando nós em níveis mais profundos."_
Estou ciente disso, não me preocupei em desalocar porque ainda nem consegui criar _rsrs_.

Comment: @Matheus Resposta editada. Quanto ao primeiro item, eu havia essquecido de dizer que me referia a variável `dicio`.

Comment: Consegui subir mais um degrau na escada da estrutura de dados, obrigado! Só mais uma dúvida: o ponteiro do tipo arvore `raiz` possui quatro bytes (int) que armazenam endereço, e os bytes seguintes dados da struct arvore(n, *esq, *dir)? Não entendi se `raiz` armazena só um ponteiro pra memória ou toda struct.

Comment: @Matheus O tamanho do ponteiro depende da plataforma. Se não me engano, em programas compilados com arquiteturas de 32 bits ele tem 4 e ccom arquiteturas de 64 bits ele tem 8 bytes, mas posso estar enganado. O ponteiro aponta para algum lugar no heap. Nesse lugar está alocado a estrutura. O tamanho da estrutura pode ser computado com `sizeof(arvore)`, tanto que é essa quantidade de memória que você aloca com o `malloc` exatamente por essa razão. [continua]

Comment: @Matheus [continuação] É de se crer que `sizeof(arvore) == sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(arvore *) + sizeof(arvore *)`, mas é permitido ao compilador acrescentar uns bytes a mais de *padding* para se aproveitar de alinhamentos de dados na memória. Também é de se esperar que todos os ponteiros tenham o mesmo tamanho, seja ele 4 ou 8 bytes (em arquiteturas de 16 bits isso não acontecia, havia dois tipos de ponteiros, `near` e `far` de tamanhos diferentes). [continua]

Comment: @Matheus [continuação] De acordo com [**este teste**](https://ideone.com/zHKfY2), o `unsigned int` tem 4 bytes, cada ponteiro tem 8 bytes, os componentes da estrutura somam 20 bytes, mas o tamanho da estrutura é de 24 bytes, havendo portanto 4 bytes de sobra (*padding*). Mas novamente, isso daí é algo que o compilador tem poder de decidir e depende da plataforma, do compilador em questão, de otimizações aplicadas, do ambiente de execução, etc.

Comment: @Matheus https://ideone.com/ft87Kj